# Admob ANR on AdView.loadAd, google play-services lib problem?

Tags: android, admob, google-play-services, android-anr-dialog

Sometimes I notice `ANR` of `AdView.loadAd` method.

From `traces.txt`:

```
"main" prio=5 tid=1 Blocked
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x742c42a0 self=0xb4d36500
  | sysTid=22581 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0xb6f46b34
  | state=S schedstat=( 754372172 125625046 868 ) utm=54 stm=21 core=2 HZ=100
  | stack=0xbe269000-0xbe26b000 stackSize=8MB
  | held mutexes=
  at com.google.android.gms.dynamite.DynamiteModule.f(com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@@17.6.0:-1)
  - waiting to lock <0x0087c747> (a java.lang.Class<com.google.android.gms.dynamite.DynamiteModule>) held by thread 14
  at com.google.android.gms.dynamite.DynamiteModule.c(com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@@17.6.0:1)
  at qd3.d(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite@@20.2.0:5)
  at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.t.j(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite@@20.2.0:11)
  at com.google.android.gms.ads.b.b(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite@@20.2.0:1)
  at y4.m(AdAdaptive.kt:2)
  at y4.<init>(AdAdaptive.kt:15)
  at com.example.ActivityMain.onCreate(ActivityMain.java:9)
  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6251)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java:-1)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke!(Native method)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

`y4.m` from the stracktrace is `loadAd` method of `AdView`
`loadAd` method have to be called on the Main thread.
Sample code: [Adaptive Banners](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/banner/adaptive#adaptive_banner_ad_size_apis)

Do you also have such this ANR?

Comment: Have same problem, but no solution. Same when start loading interstitial ad.